# Conditions for Convergence of Difference Quotients to Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am working on exercise 19 in chapter 5 of Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis. Here is the question:

> 19. Suppose $f$ is defined in $(-1, 1)$ and $f'(0)$ exists. Suppose $-1 <
>     \alpha_n < \beta_n < 1$, $\alpha \to 0$, and $\beta \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Define the difference quotients.
>
> $$ D_n = \frac{f(\beta_n) - f(\alpha_n)}{\beta_n - \alpha_n}. $$
>
> Prove the following statements:
>
> (a) If $\alpha_n < 0 < \beta$, then $\lim D_n = f'(0)$.
>
> (b) If $0 < \alpha_n < \beta_n$, and $\{\beta_n / (\beta_n - \alpha_n) \}$ is bounded, then $\lim D_n = f'(0)$.
>
> (c) If $f'$ is continuous in (-1, 1), then $\lim D_n = f'(0)$.
>
> Give an example in which $f$ is differentiable in $(-1, 1)$ (but $f'$
> is not continuous at $0$) and in which $\alpha_n, \beta_n$ tend to $0$
> in such a way that $\lim D_n$ exists but is different from $f'(0)$.

My question is about part (c). I see that I can use the mean value theorem and continuity of $f'$ at $0$ to prove the result. However, I have another argument which doesn't seem to use the continuity of the derivative at $0$ (which should be impossible) and can't find where the problem is. Here is my argument:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $f'$ is differentiable at $0$, $f$ is continuous at $0$, so the function
$$
\frac{f(\beta_n) - f(x)}{\beta_n - x}
$$
is also continuous at 0. Thus we can find $\delta$ such that for $|x| < \delta$,
$$
\left|\frac{f(\beta_n) - f(x)}{\beta_n - x} - \frac{f(\beta_n) - f(0)}{\beta_n}\right| < \epsilon.
$$

Take $N_1$ to be such that $n \geq N_1$ implies $|a_n| < \delta$.

Now by definition of the derivative we can also find $N_2$ such that $n \geq N_2$ implies

$$
\left| \frac{f(\beta_n) - f(0)}{\beta_n} - f'(0) \right| < \epsilon.
$$

Then taking $N = \max(N_1, N_2)$, and applying the triangle inequality we see that

\begin{align*}
&\left|\frac{f(\beta_n) - f(\alpha_n)}{\beta_n - \alpha_n} - f'(0)\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{f(\beta_n) - f(\alpha_n)}{\beta_n - \alpha_n}
- \frac{f(\beta_n) - f(0)}{\beta_n}
+ \frac{f(\beta_n) - f(0)}{\beta_n}
- f'(0) \right| \\
&< 2\epsilon
\end{align*}

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: The first statement is wrong, if $f'$ is continuous at $0$, how do you know the quotient is continuous? (Because you are using the fact the derivative is continuous)

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that $f$ is continuous at 0 since it's differentiable at 0. The quotient is continuous because a quotient of continuous functions is continuous, no?

Comment: Is it? $f(x)=\sin (x) $ is continuous at $x=0$ and $g(x)=x$ is continuous at $x=0$, then is $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ continuous at $x=0$?

Comment: I am assuming that $\beta_n$ is not zero in which case the quotient will be continuous (as a function of x). But I guess my problem is with that assumption. Does the result hold then if $\beta_n$ is not 0 for all n? That would be a significant strengthening of part (b) so I feel like there's something else wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the delta you obtained from the continuity of
$$
\frac{f(\beta_n) - f(x)}{\beta_n - x}
$$
Depends on $\beta_n$. So the difference won't necessarily continue to be small when $\beta_n$ changes.

Also note that if we first find $n$ so that $\beta_n$ is small (and nonzero), then for that particular $\beta_n$ by your argument, we can make the difference quotient $D_n$ close to the derivative for a particular $n$. Even though this won't continue to hold for other $n$, by repeating this process for ever smaller epsilon, we can find a convergent subsequence that converves to the derivative.

This also explains why for any counterexample to the sequence $D_n$ converging to the derivative, the limit of $D_n$ will not exist at all. If it exists, then it's limit is the limit of the subsequence we construct via your argument.